# Sync database between Mac and PC

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, bitbucket

I have a repository on Bitbucket that contains all the files for my MySQL database. I'm using XAMPP on both the PC and the Mac.

When I pull all updates on the Mac and try to start up MySQL in XAMPP, it won't start and I don't know why.

Is there something I'm missing? How would I sync a database between a Mac and a PC?

Comment: Which files, in particular?

Comment: Everything in the MySQL folder in XAMPP (basically the entire database).

Comment: So, not just the files in the `mysql/data` folder?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just that folder.